# How many elements in $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ are conjugate to $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \mu\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, general-linear-group

How many elements in $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ are conjugate to $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \mu\end{pmatrix}$ for fixed, distinct $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{F}_p$, $p$ prime?

I tried arguing that we have $\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}$ choices for the first eigenvector (division due to rescaling), then $\frac{p^2-p}{p-1}$ for the second eigenvector similarly. This is for any pair of eigenvalues, so divide through by $\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}$ to get this particular pair  $\lambda, \mu$. So,

$$\frac{(p^2-1)(p^2-p)}{(p-1)^4}.$$

But this is not an integer for certain $p$ (try $p=7$), so it can't be right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your final division. You just need to pick the eigenspaces; why are you dividing by $(p-1)^2$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For the particular choice of eigenvalues.

Comment: That makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean in your question by "for any pair of eigenvalues", nor is it clear what you mean in your comment by "for the particular choice of eigenvalues".

In any case, the final division is incorrect. As you have correctly stated, we have $\frac{p^2 - 1}{p-1}$ choices for the eigenvector (up to scaling), corresponding to the specific given eigenvalue $\mu$. Then, we have $\frac{p^2 - p}{p-1}$ choices for the second eigenvector, corresponding to the (distinct) eigenvalue $\lambda$. Once the eigenspaces for $\mu$ and $\lambda$ have been selected, the corresponding transformation is **completely** and **uniquely** specified. So, your total should be
$$
\frac{(p^2 - 1)(p^2 - p)}{(p-1)^2} = p(p+1).
$$

---

Another justification of the formula, per my comment below.

There are $p+1$ distinct one-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb F_p$. We select one of these subspaces as our eigenspace associated with $\mu$ and another as our eigenspace associated with $\lambda$, leading to our answer of $(p+1)p$.

To see that there are $p+1$ distinct one dimensional subspaces, it suffices to note that $p$ of these subspaces are spanned by a vector of the form $(1,k)$ for some $k \in \Bbb F_p$ and the remaining subspace is spanned by the vector $(1,0)$.

Comment: @arturo Well sure, as the the question states, $\mu,\lambda$ are distinct

Comment: Didn't even notice that...

Comment: So there are $p+1$ one-dimensional subspaces of the vector space $\mathbb F_p\times \mathbb F_p$ over the field $\mathbb F_p$? We chose the one of them to be eigenspace for $\lambda$, so we have $p$ choices remaining for eigenspace of $\mu$? Is this observation I made by looking at the formula true?

Comment: @Nothingspecial Yes, that's exactly correct. If you want another way to count the $p+1$ one-dimensional subspaces, note that $p$ of the subspaces are spanned by a vector of the form $(1,k)$ for some $k \in \Bbb F_p$ and the remaining subspace is spanned by $(0,1)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Amazing..! This approach deserves to be an answer or at least be included in your answer because of your concluding statement which got me thinking in this direction... :)

Comment: @Nothingspecial I've added it in. By the way, if you find this kind of analysis engaging, I recommend you look into [finite geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometry) and particularly the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane); might be a nice digression for your blog.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I just took introductory linear algebra & ring theory in college. I found these subjects engaging... I learned about finite fields & began some problem solving online; I was obsessed with questions like "How many matrices over this field satisfies this condition?"... I never looked at this from geometric perspective, (rather as combinatorics only)... I will look into finite geometry for sure... Looks interesting! Thank you.